# Can't change tabbar label's color

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to change my active tab title color, I tried using tabBarOptions but It just won't work.

```js
Home: {
  screen: TabNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
          <Ionicons
            name={focused ? 'ios-home' : 'ios-home-outline'}
            size={26}
            style={{ color: focused ? `${tabBarColor}` : tintColor }}
          />
        ),
        header: null,
      }),
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Profile',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
          <Ionicons
            name={focused ? 'ios-people' : 'ios-people-outline'}
            size={26}
            style={{ color: focused ? `${tabBarColor}` : tintColor }}
          />
        ),
        header: null,
      }),
    },
  }),
    tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: `${tabBarColor}`,
  }
}
```

I read the documentation and searched for examples but couldn't find anything that worked for me.
It's like the app is just ignoring the tabBarOptions.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16):

Maybe a little bit late to answer, but here is another valid solution for the problem, since the link in the already existing answer is broken.

You do not need to create a custom component to change the text color in the tab bar.

```js
navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Navigation Title',
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#000',
    inactiveTintColor: '#fff',
  },
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused} /* Change the icon */
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-link' : 'md-link'} />
  ),
};
```

By using the `activeTintColor` and `inactiveTintColor` props in `tabBarOptions`, you can manipulate the color of the text in the tab bar.
As @Ravi Raj mentioned in the last comment, ***you should do it for each of the tabs in the tab bar***.

Comment: adding the active tine color to my BottomTab.Navigator tabBarOptions did it thanks

Answer (score 7):

> Looks like from the documentation to change tabBarLabel **style**, you
>   need to provide custom component to **tabBarLabel** props and update based on focused.

try this

```
navigationOptions: () => ({
  tabBarLabel: ({focused}) => <MyTabBarLabel title={i18n.t('common.request')} focused={focused} />,
  tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => <MyTabBarIcon icon='requests' focused={focused}/>
})
```

> Example for MyTabBarLabel component

```
export default function MyTabBarLabel (props) {

  return (
    <WFText style={[styles.tabBarLabel,  props.focused? styles.tabBarLabelActive : {}]} >{props.title}</WFText>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabBarLabel: {
    paddingBottom: 6,
    fontSize: 10,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  tabBarLabelActive: {
    color: 'red'
  }
});
```

Replace with your components in place of MyTabBarLabel and MyTabBarIcon

Refer:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#Screen-Navigation-Options

Comment: First of all, thanks :D, Where should I add it? and where did you find this doc? I looked now at the docs again and can't see it there.

Comment: I have added the reference now check

Comment: Thanks, but I can still see the tabBarOptions solution in there, are you sure it changed? I also don't get where should I add your solution to.

Comment: Override the `navigationOptions` for each screen in TabNavigator to give custom styles for label and icon for each Tabs dynamicaly. Whereas tabBarOptions  is used to provide styles for the tab like its height, whole tab color, individual tab styles etc. But u can't use `tabBarOptions`  for changing styles dynamically like to change color of label or icon on focus. For that u need to use `navigationOptions` and override it for each tab screen and use its focused prop to check and update the label color and icon.

Answer (score 3):

In NavigationContainer **V6**

```js
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
    tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
  })}
>
```