# Change Color Of Active TabBarIcon React Native

Tags: react-native, colors, expo, vector-icons

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520890/cant-change-tabbar-labels-color), but I want to change the color of the *icon* as well - not just the text.

Here is the code in question:

```
HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#6CC7BD',
    inactiveTintColor: '#CCCCCC',
  },
  tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-information-circle'
      }
    />
  )
}
```

According to [this thread on Github](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1781), I should try this:

```
HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#6CC7BD',
    inactiveTintColor: '#CCCCCC',
  },

  tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => <TabBarIcon name={
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
      : 'md-information-circle'
  } color={this.activeTintColor}/>
}
```

But the information circle is still grey:
[image]

Also tried `color={this.tabBarOptions.activeTintColor}`, which caused an error:

[image]

Any other suggestions?

**Edit** - Also tried:

```
HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#6CC7BD',
    inactiveTintColor: '#CCCCCC',
  },
  tabBarIcon: ({activeTintColor}) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      activeTintColor={activeTintColor}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-information-circle${activeTintColor ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-information-circle'
      }
      color={this.activeTintColor}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi!
Where `TabBarIcon` come from? Is it custom or you import it from a react-navigation package?

Answer (score 2):

did you try to  add  all the props:

```
tabBarIcon: ({focused, ...restProps}) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-information-circle${activeTintColor ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-information-circle'
      }
      focused={focused}
      {...restProps}
    />
  )
```